# Symfony Tranlsation on production / server

Tags: php, symfony

everyone,

I am using Symfony 5.6 with PHP 8.1 and I have the next situation:
In dev mode my translations look good, when I deploy to prod on the local machine they are still ok, but no the server they look like **admin.app\entity\invoice\invoice.number** the translation key in the yaml file for this text is **"admin.invoice.number"** . I deleted caches many times, uploaded all the files again on the server and nothing. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: You can switch to prod mode in your local machine to debug i think you are missing something into your prod configuration folder

Comment: @YoussefSaoubou I already did it, I have no idea where the problem could be.